# Phonegap Enterprise iOS App without app store

Tags: ios, cordova, ipad, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I am developing a Phonegap Enterprise App for iPad. I have two questions...

Can I use the Apple Developer Enterprise Program for a Phonegap application?

Is there an alternative solution within the Phonegap framework for this (like build)?

I'm a bit of a newb to Phonegap so apologies if these are silly questions.

Comment: You can open the Phonegap code App in Xcode for app build. and you can use the same procedure for this code as we use for Apple codde for Apple Developer Enterprise Program.

Comment: Cool. That answers my question. I appreciate your response. Do you know if there is any additional cost for the distribution of applications or is it all included within the Apple Developer Enterprise Program package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your questions

1) Can I use the Apple Developer Enterprise Program for a Phonegap application?

Yes. The apple developer enterprise program allows you to sign and distribute applications within your own company and not necessarily the store at large. They will give you the appropriate keys and such. PhoneGap can be used to compile it.

http://docs.build.phonegap.com/en_US/3.1.0/signing_signing-ios.md.html

2) Is there an alternative solution within the Phonegap framework for this (like build)?

Yes-ish. But it would be very hacky. Apple's bread and butter is apps so phonegap Developer is the best you can get like this but it will always be cumbersome. The real route will be to pay the $299 per year or whatever they charge.

Comment: Cool. I appreciate your response. Is there any additional cost for the distribution of applications or is it all included within the package?

Comment: I haven't done the enterprise development route myself. It seems as though the annual fee is all there is. When you say enterprise application do you mean application built to be run and distributed within a single company to satisfy that specific company's needs? Or something else? Because that is what they mean.

Comment: Yes. A single company application (like an instruction manual). There might be a few third party contractors that would install it too

Comment: Well yeah that sounds like what they mean. My guess is they charge a little more than they would to place it in the store because they will not be generating any revenue from sales. Also the fee might be lower because they are also not responsible for distribution. On other platforms (android) it would be completely free to do the same thing.

Comment: That makes sense! Thanks for your help